# How does the diamond magnet work?

Tags: best-fiends-forever

The diamond magnet states that it gives you an increased chance to "Double Diamonds".

[image: diamond magnet]

When does this effect happen?

Comment: Probably when you get a chance to get diamonds.

Answer (score -2):

I assume it is a chance to double the diamonds you get from the 6 hour gift. Or when you get diamonds randomly in helicopters.